# Is there a way to get the labels of running GTK applications?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I am trying to extract labels of widgets of running GTK applications. I tried using GtkParasite but I have no idea how to get it working in my python program.

I want to be able to get the widgets and their labels of a gtk application that is running on my computer. It means that if I run gedit on my system then i want to get the labels of the widgets at run time. I hope this makes sense.

Is there a way to use the C library of GTK to get an instance of a running GTK application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably should look at accessibility libraries, such as ATK.

Comment: @el.pescado could you point me to a link that could help me start with ATK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably should use accessibility libraries - those are tools that allow eg. screen readers to read GUI labels for visually impaired users. On Linux, [at-spi2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_Technology_Service_Provider_Interface) seems to be the de-facto standard.

For Python, take look at at-spi examples:
https://github.com/infapi00/at-spi2-examples

Comment: Thank you so much @el.pescado. Seriously, i can't thank you enough. I've been stuck at this for days. :)